# Is it possible to make a third-party mutable struct "more immutable" via F#?

Tags: c#, f#, immutability, mutable

For example, wouldn't this type:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.aspx

... having public mutable fields like this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.x.aspx

... single-handedly make consuming F# code's immutability efforts kind of useless?

PS: performance must be preserved, no wrapping or dynamic instantiation of throw-away values.

PPS: I did some research and suspect the answer (negative) but would appreciate some input. It seems like a typical problem when not implementing everything in F# from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For collections of [structs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233233.aspx), this is not an issue. The collection remains immutable irrespective of the struct's members, since getting the struct from the collection returns a copy. Altering this copy does not alter the collection's contents.

Elsewhere, structs can be used to write wrappers without additional GC load. This requires to create methods for all features you want to keep and have them call the original methods. Unless the JIT doesn't inline the calls, this shouldn't cost performance. However, when wrapping reference types, this will create an empty default constructor on the wrapper type, resulting in a null reference if this constructor is called.

*As a side note, I wouldn't recommend using vector classes from outside F#, since they are not unit-of-measure aware. In my experience, most vectors can be assigned physical units, which makes code safer and more readable.*

Comment: 1. Very helpful, I did a quick experiment and it's true. Did not consider this.
2. A valid point as well, maybe overhead is not too much.
3. This is an important point for me, I keep think about units of measure.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, the short answer is no. However, at least in the case of the Vector2 class you show, many of the operations are implemented in an immutable fashion when you use the static versions of the methods. For example

```
var vecB = Vector2.Normalize(vecA);
```

is an immutable call.  Unless the libraries you are using support some kind of immutability, you are stuck with having to implement the immutable functionality you want to have.

F# has a design goal of being a hybrid of mutable and immutable content so that it can access the rich functionality of .NET libraries when needed.

Comment: Yes, that mutability was a conscience performance choice from the framework's designers. My only problem is desire to make sure when I do something like: IReadonlyCollection<Vector2> GetReadonlyView() then nobody can change even members. It is sad that it's unachievable (performance-wise). I am also looking for any strong reasons to be using F# without too much luck so far...

Comment: There's also an argument that for something like a graphics application where you are having rapid changes, that the overhead of creating new objects for each operation will invoke the GC more often than is necessary than if you can modify the field values directly. Immutability is great for complex applications, but isn't always a better choice for every situation.